# Optimize the number of connections of the connection pool and MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, java, connection-pooling, max-connections

We are using Oracle Cloud's Ampere A1 instance consisting of 4 OCPUs (equivalent to 4 vCPUs) and 24GB of usable memory on Oracle Linux 7.9.

On the server is running an java game server and a web server, both are used with MySQL 5.x. With the game server written in Java, we are using [proxool](https://proxool.sourceforge.net/), targeting up to 250 concurrent users. And with web server (currently using Apache) can be up to 1000 concurrent users.
If based on [the formula](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing#the-formula):

```
connections = ((core_count * 2) + effective_spindle_count)
```

But the boot volume that the instance uses is now no longer HDD, so the value of the parameter `effective_spindle_count` is still a mystery on SSD.

So with the properties [`maximum-connection-count`](https://proxool.sourceforge.net/properties.html#maximum-connection-count), [`minimum-connection-count`](https://proxool.sourceforge.net/properties.html#minimum-connection-count), [`simultaneous-build-throttle`](https://proxool.sourceforge.net/properties.html#simultaneous-build-throttle), [`prototype-count`](https://proxool.sourceforge.net/properties.html#prototype-count) which formula should be used? And what is the recommended value of these properties?

This is the current [my.cnf](https://pastebin.com/u60VWMLa) configuration. Based on the above information and current configuration files, what is the calculation formula and the recommended value for the `max_connections` system variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use any "formulas" for tuning databases. They're all wrong, because they don't take into account the specific needs of your database and your application requests.

The size of your connection pool really has nothing to do with your CPUs or your disk spindles. It has to do with how many concurrent connections your application needs.

The number of concurrent connections your application needs has nothing to do with the number of concurrent users. It has to do with the number of concurrent transactions your application runs.

At any given moment, many threads of your application might be running only non-database code, calculating game results or whatever. They are not using a database connections in that moment, so they have no need to increase the pool size.

I've supported high-traffic databases with dozens of app servers, and dozens of threads in each app server. In spite of this level of concurrency, if I monitor the `Threads_running` status variable in MySQL, it's pretty low. Usually between 10 and 30. This indicates how many clients are actually running a query at that moment.

If you code your app so that clients acquire a connection, use it, and release it as soon as they're done with the transaction, then you can make a connection pool that is relatively small. Probably 20-40 per app server is plenty for a typical application.

But there's no single right answer, because it depends on your code.

If there's no formula, how can you size the connection pool?

**Monitor the connection usage.**

Watch `Threads_connected`, `Threads_running` in the database. Correlate this with the application traffic.

Also watch your Java connection pool. It should give you statistics about how many connections are in use, and how many connections are idle in the pool.

Over time, you will get to know how many connections are used relative to the number of concurrent users. It's probably not a precise formula. It's going to rise and fall within a range.

Operating an online service is complex. The reason we call managing the server resources "tuning" is that we have to continually adjust it as we get feedback from the system.

Good luck!

Comment: I used the query `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`. I see the [`Max_used_connections`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-status-variables/#max_used_connections) variable, as explained by the documentation, can I set `max_connections` equal to or rounded up the value closest to the value of this variable? With the variable `Threads_connected`, because there is not only a java game server but also a web server, and according to [MariaDB's documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-status-variables/#threads_connected), it is incorrect when the thread pool is used, so I have no idea with it at the moment.

Comment: I don't use MariaDB. I thought you tagged the question MySQL and you said you were using MySQL 5.x. Please tag your questions accurately in the future.

Comment: MySQL also has a similar [`Max_used_connections`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Max_used_connections) variable. There seems to be no difference between MariaDB and MySQL on version 5.x.

Comment: With _proxool_, assuming I have calculated the value of the `maximum-connection-count` property (eg is 50), how much should I set the value of the [`minimum-connection-count`](https://proxool.sourceforge.net/properties.html#minimum-connection-count)? And is it fine if I set it to **0**?